# How to load an include file from Drupal's include folder?

Tags: 7

I am experiencing a problem with the GlobalRedirect module in that it seems like it is not loading the locale.inc which it relies upon. I tried using the module_load_include function but did not work as locale.inc isn't apart of a module.

I know I can use:

```
include(DRUPAL_ROOT."/includes/locale.inc");
```

Is there a Drupal specific function call to load include files for Drupal? I am curious if there is.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of module_load_include() method you can include the core files from the include directory the only thing is you need to pass "content" in the second parameter (i.e: module name).

Working Example on including a file from drupal core includes directory,

```
module_load_include('inc', 'content', 'includes/actions');
```

Comment: Never realized I could include these files using `module_load_include`

Comment: It was the 'content' keyword that I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: it seems to me the OPs original method is fine (and shorter) - what am I missing?

Comment: This approach causes the warnings "The following module is missing from the file system: content", and is not the correct approach.  See @LionsAd's solution instead for the right way.

Answer (score 8):

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/actions.inc';
```

is the correct way.

Using 'content' just worked, because there is no module named content and just did work due to a side-effect. It also caused silent performance problems on Drupal versions < 7.50.

There is no Drupal specific function to load a core include file, and this is how it is done in includes/common.inc line 5242.

- Fabianx, Drupal 7 core branch maintainer and core committer

Comment: > 7.50 you'll end up with "The following module is missing from the file system: content" errors